# Spreadsheets: Is there any cloud-based spreadsheet that can give user-based access to edit a column?

Tags: webapp-rec

We're looking at a way to share inventory information across multiple users: sales, customer service, production, etc. Is there a way to lock the 'Price' column so that it can be edited only specific user, say - the production team member?

What cloud-based service offers this functionality?

Comment: Does one of the answers given, answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

[Google Sheets allows you to protect specific cell ranges so only certain users can edit them.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)

Answer (score -1):

The service offered by [smartsheet.com](http://www.smartsheet.com) facilitates locking by column, limiting changes to users with 'Admin' status for that sheet.

Comment: If downvoting, it wouldn't hurt to explain (just for other readers) the motivation -- simply as a service to others. Is smartsheet.com no longer in business? Is locking by column no longer available?

Answer (score -1):

The service offered by [ragic.com](http://www.ragic.com) allows you to hide different fields or make them read only, and has many ways of [configuring user access rights](http://www.ragic.com/intl/en/doc/11/Access-Rights).