# How can I share individual columns of an online spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, privacy, sharing

I sometimes use a spreadsheet when grading student assignments, where the leftmost columns describe the different parts of the assignments and possible points, and there is a column for each student.  I'd like to make it so students can see just the columns of the spreadsheet that pertain to them (i.e., the leftmost ones and their personal column). Google spreadsheets doesn't let me do this (without making individual copies of columns into a new spreadsheet for each student). Is there a way to just share the information I want?

I saw the question [Spreadsheets: Is there any cloud-based spreadsheet that can give user-based access to edit a column?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/spreadsheets-is-there-any-cloud-based-spreadsheet-that-can-give-user-based-acce), but none of the answers seem suitable, since I am interested in viewing, not editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ImportRange function to sync cell data between two spreadsheets. You could then share the individual spreadsheets to your various students.

ImportRange documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

I've created an example for you, here is your master sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12uwNzqrJ4lzJv-0vdFszM-HTl4S8PSh1avkyyisxgyw/edit?usp=sharing

And here is a "student" sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XI0JDq-K9HTs0hcF9waVj4O3161m9c-rjwEEH3hrPiA/edit#gid=0